# Error: On docker compose up - it was not possible to find any installed .net core sdks

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

When I run the command

`docker-compose up`

It shows error:

> It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from: https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

When I run the command

`docker run -it --name core-api -p 8888:80 core_api`

it doesn't show the last error and api goes up well.

I'm using this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  core-api:
    container_name: core-api
    image: core_api
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
  ui:
    container_name: ui
    image: ui
    ports:
      - "8889:80"
    volumes:
      - /opt/volumes/app/ui:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /opt/volumes/app/ui_config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - core-api
```

I installed the .Net core sdk on the host but it didn't work.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What is the `core_api` image you have specified in the docker-compose file, and is the underscore a typo (in your docker run command you're using a hyphen instead)?

Comment: I created the image with the name core_api, the image works when i execute the command docker run...